# socket.io in node.js is not working on 3G mobile network

Tags: node.js, networking, mobile, socket.io, 3g

socket.io in node.js is not working on 3G mobile network.

I have tried these things already:

```
 io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
 io.set('browser client minification', true);
 io.set('browser client etag', true);
```

Comment: does socket.io logs anything besides heartbeats, what about handshakes?

Answer (score 3):

Mobile networks do all sorts of things to mangle data.  It is very common to see aggressive proxy servers, compression and transformation of data, and poor adherence to spec along the way.

I have noticed in particular that WebSockets connections often fail.  You are doing the right thing by only enabling AJAX transports.  If that fails, there isn't much you can do to resolve the problem.

You might try running your Socket.IO server on a port other than 80.  At least with my Sprint connection, I can run pure websockets on port 3000, but it fails on port 80.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove this from your code:

```
io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
```

Because socket.io tries all available transports before finally giving up. However, you've enable only one transport which might be causing error